# Web-Scraping with Login and Redirect using R and rvest/httr

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I would like to scrape information from a webpage. There is a login screen, and when I am logged in, I can access all kinds off pages from which I would like to scrape information (such as the last name of a player, the object `.lastName`).
I am using R and the packages `rvest` and `httr`.

Somehow, the login seems to work, but I am clueless how to be redirected to the page I need to get the info from.

The login form can be accessed on `http://kickbase.sky.de/anmelden` and the relevant pages have the form `http://kickbase.sky.de/spielerprofil/player-name/number`, e.g. `http://kickbase.sky.de/spielerprofil/nadiem-amiri/1639#`.

Here is the code I used. Thank you very much for your help.

```
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("httr")
library(rvest)
library(httr)

handle <- handle("http://kickbase.sky.de")  # Create handle
path   <- "anmelden" #  Login Path

# fields found in the login form.
login <- list(
  email = "testscrape@gmail.com"
  ,password  = "tester"
  ,redirect_url =  # I want to be redirected to this page and then scrape info from here
    "http://kickbase.sky.de/spielerprofil/nadiem-amiri/1639#"
)

response <- POST(handle = handle, path = path, body = login)

webpage <- read_html(response)
name_data <- html_text(html_nodes(webpage, ".lastName"))
name_data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
url<-"https://kickbase.sky.de/"
page<-html_session(url)
page<-rvest:::request_POST(page,url="https://kickbase.sky.de/api/v1/user/login",
                           body=list("email"="testscrape@gmail.com",
                                     "password"="tester",
                                     "redirect_url"="http://kickbase.sky.de/spielerprofil/nadiem-amiri/1639#"),
                         encode='json'
                           )
player_page<-jump_to(page,"https://kickbase.sky.de/api/v1/news?skip=0&player=1639&limit=3")
data<-jsonlite::fromJSON(readBin(player_page$response$content,what="json"))

print(data)
```

Please note that the website provides an API and that is where you get the data
`https://kickbase.sky.de/api/v1/news?skip=0&player=1639&limit=3`

variable `data` has all the information needed

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful reply. How is it possible to know if a page has an API?

Comment: [image](https://i.imgur.com/ZSzhlbz.png)
Use your Chrome developer tools to determine what are the requests happening in a browser when you load a page. Clicking 'XHR' as shown in the image will help you to filter all the XHR requests which helped me to figure out the json response of the request

Comment: @Bharath Many years later `request_POST()` is deprecated.  Do you know the new way?

Comment: @joshbrows Try `html_form()` and its sibling functions.